# resizing partitions

Tags: grub2, partitioning, boot-failure, bootloader, resize

I have the following configuration:

- sda1 1 GB maybe fat32 (windows recovery partition)
- sda2 40 GB ntfs(windows drive c) with boot flag
- sda3 around 100GB ntfs(storage partition)
- sda4 extended partition:

  - sda5 10 GB ext4 partition
  - sda6 1 GB linux swap

I want to make this changes:

- sda2 30 GB resize(decrease size with 10 GB)
- sda3 around 100GB(move and maybe decrease size with 4-5 GB)
- sda4 around 20-22 GB (move and increase size with 10-15GB)
- sda5 around 20 GB (move and increase size with 10-12 GB)
- sda6 2 GB (move and increase size with 1 GB)

Is it safe to do this operations?

Will i lose grub?

I will do the changes with gparted on puppy linux live usb.

Comment: May be because of I have awaken at this very momento but I don't understand all that stuff (but as I say: maybe it's only me). A graphic representation of your partitions or a screenshot of a tool like gparted showing your current partitions will be easier than trying to understand that stuff. Sorry, maybe I need to go back to sleep and be back later... Oh BTW, illustrating in text mode only your partitions may also be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Ok.Short explanation:
sda2 is boot partition
grub is on sda5(extended partition with ubuntu on it)
sda2 will only be shrinked.All other partition will be moved and resized.Will this operations may break grub or not?
Or will i have to instal grub in MBR with grub customizer?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to resize partitions?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Is it safe to do this operations?* - no, it is NOT safe, just as any operation with partitions. You're advised to make a backup of all your important data before doing any modifications. That said, it *usually* works well.

*Will i lose grub?* - you may lose it, but it's easy to re-install it using the [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) tool. You can do this straight from the Ubuntu Live CD (or possibly from puppy linux, I'm not sure, I would just use Ubuntu LiveCD)

Comment: I have made all operations successfuly.Thank you for your answer!